# How do I use distributed DNN training in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, deep-learning, tensorflow

Google released TensorFlow today.

I have been poking around in the code, and I don't see anything in the code or API about training across a cluster of GPU servers.

Does it have distributed training functionality yet?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Updated:**

- [Distributed TensorFlow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)
- [Distributed TensorFlow Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime#distributed-tensorflow)

The release occurred on 2/26/2016 and was announced by coauthor Derek Murray in the original issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23#issuecomment-189285409) and uses [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/) for inter-process communication.

**Previous:**

Before the update above, a distributed implementation of **TensorFlow** had not been released yet. Support for a distributed implementation was the topic of [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23) where coauthor Vijay Vasudevan [wrote](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23#issuecomment-155151640):

> we are working on making a distributed implementation available, it's
>   currently not in the initial release

and Jeff Dean later provided [an update](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23#issuecomment-155608002):

> Our current internal distributed extensions are somewhat entangled
>   with Google internal infrastructure, which is why we released the
>   single-machine version first. The code is not yet in GitHub, because
>   it has dependencies on other parts of the Google code base at the
>   moment, most of which have been trimmed, but there are some remaining
>   ones.
>
> We realize that distributed support is really important, and it's one
>   of the top features we're prioritizing at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

It took us a few months, but today marks the release of the initial [distributed TensorFlow runtime](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime). This includes support for multiple machines, each with multiple GPUs, with communication provided by [gRPC](http://grpc.io).

The current version includes the necessary backend components so that you can assemble a cluster manually and connect to it from a client program. More details are available in the [readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

As you may have noticed. Tensorflow has already supported distributed DNN training for quite some time. Please refer to its offcial website for details.

=========================================================================

#### Previous

No, it doesn't support distribute training yet, which is a little disappointing. But I don't think it is difficult to extend from single machine to multi-machine. Compared to other open source libraries, like Caffe, TF's data graph structure is more suitable for cross-machine tasks.

Comment: this should be deleted as it's not true anymore